# How to apply the same awk action to different files?

Tags: shell, awk

I am new in awk and I do not know if it is possible to write an awk script that does this:

I have hundred of data files that I have to sort. For each one I use the following one-liner:

```
awk 'ORS=NR%3?" ":"\n" ' file1.tex >  file1_sorted.tex
awk 'ORS=NR%3?" ":"\n" ' file2.tex >  file2_sorted.tex
...
```

and I get the output I need. However I would like to have an script to automate this action, taking each file, applying the action and writing the corresponding sorted file.

I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you modify the `awk` code, can be solved by a single `awk` process and no shell loop:

```
awk 'FNR==1{if(o)close(o);o=FILENAME;sub(/\.tex/,"_sorted.tex",o)}{ORS=FNR%3?" ":"\n";print>o}' *.tex
```

Not a beauty, just insignificantly faster.

**Explanations** as requested in comment.

`FNR` (**f**ile **n**umber or **r**ecord) is similar to `NR` (**n**umber or **r**ecord), but while `NR` is a continuous sequence number of all input records, `FNR` is reset to 1 when processing of a new input file is started.

A `gawk` 4.0 only alternative for the `FNR==1` is the `BEGINFILE` special pattern.

```
awk '
FNR==1{   # first record of an input file?
  if(o)close(o);   # was previous output file? close it
  o=FILENAME;sub(/\.tex/,"_sorted.tex",o)   # new output file name
}
{
  ORS=FNR%3?" ":"\n";   # set ORS based on FNR (not NR as in the original code)
  print>o   # print to the current output file
}
' *.tex
```

Comment: Thanks @manatwork! That was awesome. 

Unlike the last answer, I do not get exactly how does this one-liner work, but it did. 

If you have time, I would thank you if you could explain to me what does `FNR==1` do.

=)

Answer (score 12):

You can apply the files in a for loop:

```
for file in *.tex;
do
    awk 'ORS=NR%3?" ":"\n"' "$file" > "$(basename "$file")_sorted.tex"
done
```

Or on one line:

```
for file in *.tex; do awk 'ORS=NR%3?" ":"\n"' $file > "$(basename "$file" .tex)_sorted.tex"; done
```

Since you don't specify which shell, go with the more standard `basename` instead using the shell specific syntax `${file%%.tex}`.

Comment: That “shell-specific syntax” is in POSIX and is available on practically every unix system that's still under warranty, and many that aren't.

Comment: Thanks @Arcege!,

I use _emacs_ as shell. Although your suggestion is pretty understandable, I do not know how to use it. As far as I understand and I have been practiced, one writes an _.awk_ script that you run before the file or folder you want to apply it to. Am I right?

I did that, however this seems another kind of script that I do not know how to use.

Comment: You can run a shell inside emacs (<kbd>M-x</kbd>`shell`) and run the commands above inside that at the prompt.  Or open a terminal and run the command there.  There are two ways to specify (awk, shell, etc) scripts: either on the command-line or in a file.  Your `awk` command in the posting uses the command-line form; my "one line" command is also a command-line form.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but given that the last time I saw a single core personal computer was a decade ago, you can use gnu parallel

To solve the shell expansion and interpretation of quotes

```
my_awk='ORS=NR%3?" ":"\n"'
```

Use the proper glob to select the input files. Here I'm using `{.}`
to take out the extension from the output name because I'm appending it afterwards

```
parallel -jX "awk '$my_awk' {} > {.}_sorted.tex" ::: *.tex
```

where `X` is the number of processors you want to use, still you can use 1.
This would give you `file[1-9]_sorted.tex` as  outputs