# How to grep several files using part of filename as a pattern?

Tags: files, awk, grep

I have a folder which includes several files named `order[ID].log` where `[ID]` is a string e.g.

```
orderID1.log
orderID2.log
orderID3.log
orderID4.log
...
```

I need to write a script in Linux to `grep` each file by the `ID` in their name and output the result to a file named `ID.log` 
Example:
For `orderID1.log`, I need to `grep 'ID1' orderID1.log > ID1.log`
For `orderID2.log`, I need to `grep 'ID2' orderID2.log > ID2.log`
I tried to write the script below,

```
for i in ORDER*.log 
do 
grep 'i' order$i > $i.log;
done
```

The problem here is that i will be record as "orderID1","orderID2" rather than "ID1","ID2". Is there a simple way to do this in linux ?

Comment: Hi @don_crissti, the key word will be the ID after order. To be simply, I write them as 1,2,3,4,...etc. Then I need to grep these ID in the file and save them in a new file. Unfortunately, I don't have them listed in a file.

Comment: Cool @don_crissti You are right. They are in the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to extract the `ID` substring from the file names. One way to do that is via parameter expansion e.g. `${var:offset:length}` so in your case `var` is `f`ilename, offset is `5` (`order`) and length is `${#f}-9` (that is, total length `${#f}` minus the combined length of `order` and `.log` which is `9` characters):

```
for f in order*.log                                                 
  do 
    ID=${f:5:${#f}-9}
    grep -- "$ID" "$f" > "$ID".log
  done
```

or if you prefer a one-liner:

```
for f in order*.log; do ID=${f:5:${#f}-9}; grep -- "$ID" "$f" >" $ID".log; done
```

Alternatively, you could use `awk` to apply [the same action to multiple files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32181):

```
awk '
FNR==1{
if(fname)close(fname)
id=substr(FILENAME, 6, length(FILENAME)-9)
fname=id".log"
}
$0 ~ id{
print > fname
}
' order*.log
```

This does all files with one `awk` invocation, avoiding the shell loop. In one line:

```
awk 'FNR==1{if(f)close(f);id=substr(FILENAME, 6, length(FILENAME)-9);f=id".log"} $0~id{print > f}' order*.log
```